# What css do I need to add to change the width of angular ui timepicker?

Tags: css, angularjs, width, angular-ui, timepicker

I am using an [angular ui](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/timepicker) timepicker. I've got it inside the dropdown to a [popover](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/popovers), and the timepicker hangs off the side of the dropdown. Looks kind of like this...

```
[trigger dropdown]
     _________________
    |                |
    |     ^          ^
    |  [ H H ]  : [ M M ]  [AM]       <--- hangs of the side
    |     v          v
    |                |
    |________________|
```

Here's the html

```
<!-- inside template for popover/dropdown -->

<uib-timepicker
    id= "start-time-picker"
    ng-model= "$parent.start.startTime">
</uib-timepicker>
```

I tried to do a standard width decrease with CSS.

```
<!-- inside template for popover/dropdown -->

<style>
    #start-time-picker{
        width: 50px;
    }
</style>

<uib-timepicker
    id= "start-time-picker"
    ng-model= "$parent.start.startTime">
</uib-timepicker>
```

This doesn't have any effect. I'm guessing that some other piece of css is taking precedence over the style I have attempted to introduce? How do I decrease the width of this thing so that it will fit inside the dropdown?

I guess that increasing the size of the popover container would achieve the same effect, but I'd like to decrease the width of the time picker if possible.

Edit : I'm pretty sure it is not a cache issue, bc I added this

```
<style>
    #test{
        color : red;
    }
</style>
<p id= "test">TEST</p>
```

And saw the updated red text.

Comment: Zack,can you create fiddle or codepen, couldn't replicate that issue?

Comment: Unfortunately cannot use either. Proxy/firewall settings are fairly strict here at the office.

Comment: @NagaSaiA, this worked for you though? At least the width part?

Comment: Can you share complete HTML,CSS, JS to debug easily

Comment: Let me try and make a minimum possible example for you. Right now it's sort of hard to isolate the relevant code.